# awk gensub matched the wrong number

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm trying to match the contents in the 1st [], but always get the last. What's wrong in the expression?
BTW, other fields are also needed, so awk is preferred.

```
echo "[a1 b1] [a2 b2]" | awk '{p=gensub(/.*\[(.*?)\].*/,"\\1",1); print p}'
```

want "a1 b1", but get "a2 b2". Thanks!

Comment: `echo "[a1 b1] [a2 b2]" | awk '{p=gensub(/\[([^\[]*)\].*/,"\\1",1); print p}'`?

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
echo "[a1 b1] [a2 b2]" | awk -F"[][]" '{print $2}'
```

***Explanation:*** Simply making `][` as a field separator then printing the 2nd field since fields will be divided as per mentioned field separator.

Comment: sorry, I made the question simplified, actually I want to extract "yy a1 b1" from the string "xx yy [a1 b1] / zz [a2 b2]/". Your answer is perfect with the original situation, but I still want to know the problem of my expression.

Comment: @user2524314: I suggest you start a new question.